# Primer app con React errores al ejecutar developer server

Tags: reactjs, app

Haciendo un curso todo va bien hasta que pongo en la terminal de VSC npm start y me aparece esto[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y me abre el navegador y me dice que no tengo internet y chequee mi conexion a internet[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es el index.js pero yo no lo escribí, se me generó automático

```
 import React from 'react';
 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; 
 import './index.css'; 
 import App from './App'; 
 import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals'; 
 
 ReactDOM.render( <React.StrictMode> <App /> </React.StrictMode>, document.getElementById('root') ); 
 // If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function 
 // to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log)) 
 // or send to an analytics endpoint. Learn more: bit.ly/CRA-vitals reportWebVitals();
```

Es el index.js creado por create-react-app, yo no toqué el código.

Comment: Es muy probable que ese error se deba a algún problema con tu código. Por favor, muéstranos el código que hiciste hasta ahora. Puedes editar tu pregunta y agregarlo (preferentemente en texto, no en imágenes).

Comment: Esto es el index.js pero yo no lo escribi se me genero automatico          
 import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint. Learn more: https://bit.ly/CRA-vitals
reportWebVitals();

Comment: Hola Horuuu, los errores y código que llegues a compartir hazlo en texto. Te invito a que leas [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: ``` import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint. Learn more: https://bit.ly/CRA-vitals
reportWebVitals(); ```Es el index.js creado por create-react-app   no toque el codigo

Answer (score 0):

el problema parece estar en APP.js si pudieras adjuntar un poco de codigo, podriamos ayudarte más, quizá moviste algo por error